# using "header Refresh" (PHP) + "meta refresh" (HTML) together

Tags: php, header, refresh, meta

I need to use "header Refresh" (PHP) + "meta refresh" (HTML) together, the PHP refresh is working, but the meta one is ignored, please help me, thanks

```
<? $idne2=$_GET['idne']; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat With <?="$idne2";?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://example.net">
</head>
<body>
<?
echo "You're being redirected to... page";
header("Refresh: 2; URL=ymsgr:sendIM?$idne2");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The browser will already have refreshed before your timeout on the second header (that and the browser *may* only choose to respect one of them, as it's meaningless to refresh to two different things)

Comment: As Rwoland mentioned this _can_ not work. The PHP header function only works if no output occured before (more accurate: the HTTP header has not been sent before).

My guess is that your problem is really something else and maybe you should try to give a little more insight _why_ you want to make 2 redirects (which doesn't really make sense in general).

Comment: @RowlandShaw thanks for let me know about that.. I need this 2 redirects because 1 is for apps and 1 is for website url.. if may not possible then I will use popup then. thanks

Comment: @Himhamster yes I need 2 because I need traffict from button.. thanks for let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header function will not work if there is any html output before header function.

use JS redirect.

```
 <? $idne2=$_GET['idne']; ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat With <?="$idne2";?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "You're being redirected to... page";
sleep(2);
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
     window.location.href='ymsgr:sendIM?$idne2';
     window.location.href='http://example.net';
     </SCRIPT>");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's "window.location.href='ymsgr:sendIM?me';" doing?

Comment: @Hirnhamster ymsgr:sendIM?me is for yahoo messenger, like skype: tag

Comment: @AthulAK

thanks for
window.location.href='ymsgr:sendIM?$idne2';
window.location.href='http://example.net';

but.. again, browser only detect 1 line, and ymsgr:sendIM is ignored

Comment: but it works for me... you don't have any chat client installed on your computer ?  please install Pidgin(https://www.pidgin.im/download/) and try this code again.

Comment: @AthulAK thanks for help. but I already installed original yahoo messenger app, let me try again. the javascript is ignore ymsgr:sendIM for me. thanks